# SQLite select statement from multiple tables misunderstood

Tags: sql, sqlite

Suppose we have 3 tables like so:

**tab_user** |id_usr|...|

**tab_cat** |id_cat|...|

**tab_user_cat_relationship** |id_cat(fk for tab_cat)|id_usr(fk for tab_user)|type_ac|

[image]

I need to select all users and their type_ac(from tab_user_cat) by certain category id, so I do it like so:

```
select tab_user._id, tab_user_cat.type_ac
from tab_user,tab_user_cat
where tab_user._id = tab_user_cat.fk_user_id
and tab_user_cat.fk_cat_id='01'
```

Expected response:

```
| _id|  type_ac  |

| 001|           |

| 002|           |

| 003|     B     |

| 004|     A     |
```

But I get only:

```
| _id | type_ac |

| 003|     B    |

| 004|     A    |
```

Comment: do `left outer join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

```
select tab_user._id, tab_user_cat.type_ac
from tab_user
left outer join tab_user_cat 
    on tab_user._id = tab_user_cat.fk_user_id
    and tab_user_cat.fk_cat_id='01'
```

Note :- Always use the `ANSI JOIN` syntax.